# Shading on ListCurvePathPlot

Tags: plotting, interpolation, filling

I have a series of data points describing the boundary of some region. Using `ListCurvePathPlot`, I have an easy way to get a nice curve interpolating this boundary (rather than splitting the boundary up into "upper" and "lower" curves and using regular function interpolation, which looks much worse). An example is given in the plot below.

My question is: is there an easy way to get the interior region bounded by this to be filled in?

The curve isn't closed but we can easily close off the right hand side.

[image: The data points, together with the curve generated by ListCurvePathPlot]

Here is the `Plot` function analogue of what I want to have for my curve

```
Plot[{0.5 + x^(1/3), 0.5 - x^(1/3)}, {x, 0, 1}, 
     Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

**Edit:** If you want to recreate the first figure as a minimal working example, the points I used are:

```
points = {{0.557, 0.999072}, {0.7, 0.985086}, {0.69, 0.986477}, 
          {0.6,0.987449}, {0.59, 0.987258}, {0.58, 0.987789}, 
          {0.68, 0.987633}, {0.67, 0.988555}, {0.66, 0.989164}, 
          {0.65, 0.989422}, {0.64, 0.989367}, {0.57, 0.98998}, 
          {0.56, 0.995297}, {0.63, 0.989039}, {0.62, 0.988555}, 
          {0.61, 0.987953}, {0.557, 1.0037}, {0.6, 1.01934}, 
          {0.59, 1.01729}, {0.58, 1.01505}, {0.7, 1.06133}, 
          {0.69, 1.0558}, {0.65, 1.034}, {0.64, 1.02983}, 
          {0.63, 1.02643}, {0.62, 1.0237}, {0.61, 1.02138}, 
          {0.68, 1.05046}, {0.67, 1.04468}, {0.66, 1.03896}, 
          {0.57, 1.01214}, {0.56, 1.00701}};
```

and the code is simply:

```
Show[
     ListPlot[{points}, PlotStyle -> Red], 
     ListCurvePathPlot[points, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}]]
```

Comment: Please, post the code of your problem or, at least, a MWE (minimal working example)...

Comment: Posting the list of your points would be worth considering...

Comment: Updated to reflect these suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
pts = Table[{2 t^2, t}, {t, -1, 1, 0.05}];

path = FindCurvePath[pts][[1]];
```

Using [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html)

```
Graphics[{Red, Thick, Line[pts[[path]]], LightRed, Polygon[pts[[path]]]}, 
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Using [`ListCurvePathPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCurvePathPlot.html)

```
ListCurvePathPlot[pts,
 PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thick}},
 Epilog -> {Opacity[.5, LightRed], Polygon[pts[[path]]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this looks like exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Does this help?

```
pts = Table[{2 t^2, t}, {t, -1, 1, 0.05}];
Graphics[
 {
  EdgeForm[], FaceForm[{Darker@Red, Opacity[0.25]}],
  Polygon[pts],
  Thick, Darker@Red,
  Line[pts],
  PointSize[0.02],
  Point[pts]
  },
 Axes -> True
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: This is also helpful. It makes sense that the polygon function would be effective, if the spacing is sufficiently small. I wasn't aware of this function. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function as the `PlotStyle` option setting to add `Point`s and a `Polygon`:

```
ListCurvePathPlot[points, PlotStyle -> 
 ({Red, Thickness[.01], PointSize[Large], #, Yellow, Polygon @@ #, Blue, Point @@ # } &)]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> "11.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"

Also works in

```
$Version
```

> "9.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 25, 2013)"

Using the example in Henrik's and Bob's anwers:

```
pts = Table[{2 t^2, t}, {t, -1, 1, 0.05}]; 
ListCurvePathPlot[pts, PlotStyle -> 
 ({Red, Thickness[.01], PointSize[Large], #, LightRed, Polygon @@ #, Blue, Point @@ #} &)]
```

[image]

And the first  example from [ListCurvePathPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListCurvePathPlot.html)
:

```
pts2 = Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, 50]}];
ListCurvePathPlot[pts2, PlotStyle -> 
 ({Red, Thickness[.01], PointSize[Large], #, LightRed, Polygon @@ #, Blue, Point @@ #} &)]
```

[image]